Judgement & Penalty for Sin
Given the death of Christ as being a just sacrifice for sin itself, do we still face judgement/accountability on account of those sin though not be made guilty for them?
Are the sins truly forgotten in the sense that, will it be just for God to “forget” sins caused against someone?
Hope this makes sense.

I've read this over but I still am uncertain what you are asking. I stole before I was converted to Christ and after believing, I paid back what I had stolen. I believe that Jesus Christ voluntarily suffered on my behalf. But I still wanted to put right what I had done. Is that the kind of thing that you are trying to find out ?

Welcome to the Biblical Hermeneutics forum, AnthonyJr. Please note that this forum is different than most others because it's focused on supporting any assertions with specific scriptures, opinions of experts, context, linguistic analysis, historical sources or references, and logic to build a case. Typically, these are quoted in questions and any answers for convenience. Your question needs to include at least one scripture reference to make it relevant to this forum. Please edit your answer or delete it. Thanks!

This is a question for systematic theology and is quite divisive.

I want to add to Mark Vestal's answer, although he may not agree.
It was not necessarily Jesus that was nailed to the cross, but sin itself (2Cor 5). Jesus became sin as the only embodiment that could become sin and be rescued by God.
Jesus' descent into Sheol carried sin to where it belongs into captivity. Eph 4:8 - He led captivity captive
Captivity in Proverbs 5:22 is described as sin itself, "His own iniquities entrap the wicked man, And he is caught in the cords of his sin."
Jesus became sin and guilt (His physical flesh becomes sin and naked body guilt) and His blood covered His own body (covering of sin and guilt).
Sheol is described as having 2 sides which are separated by a chasm.
The 2 sides can be inferred as being...

the side of that which is forgotten
the side of that which is remembered

Job 14:13 - “Oh, that You would hide me in the grave, That You would conceal me until Your wrath is past, That You would appoint me a set time, and remember me!
and the famous Psalm 16
For You will not leave my soul in Sheol, Nor will You allow Your Holy One to see corruption.
An interesting study is the Father's ability to forget and remember based on the work of the Son.
Does God really forget, or does He by choice choose not to remember?
Either way is victory for those who have sinned.
Romans 8:1 - There is therefore now no condemnation to those who are in Christ Jesus, who do not walk according to the flesh, but according to the Spirit.
by the death of the flesh, the spirit is made alive. Not only the death and resurrection of the Son, but also of every believer who chooses to put the flesh to death so that there can be spiritual life.
No condemnation shows God's ability to cover our nakedness and sin (forget) and find no fault. Then there is no judgment to those who follow the Son's example and they are "passed over" by God's wrath and judgement, only leaving the good works to remembered,  weighed and judged.
The justification comes from One unjustly taking the penalty and wrath, so that the unjust can become justified.
This is foreshadowed in Mark 4:37-40
A great windstorm arose, and the waves beat into the boat, so that it was already filling. But He was in the stern, asleep on a pillow. And they awoke Him and said to Him, “Teacher, do You not care that we are perishing?”
Then He arose and rebuked the wind, and said to the sea, “Peace, be still!” And the wind ceased and there was a great calm. But He said to them, “Why are you so fearful? How is it that you have no faith?”
This should be thought of as Jonah 2.0.
The God man on the boat sleeping, a tempest arises (wrath of God). The men on the boat fearful and go to get the God man. However, in the story of Mark, Jesus isn't thrown overboard but stands and rebukes (appeases) God's wrath and everyone is saved. No judgement falls on the other men. No condemnation on the entire boat. They are "passed over" because of Him.

Thanks Biff.  Very poetic answer.

The resurrection of Jesus Christ is proof that His atonement was acceptable as the sufficient payment for our sins.
2 Corinthians 5:19-21

To wit, that God was in Christ, reconciling the world unto himself, not imputing their trespasses unto them; and hath committed unto us the word of reconciliation.
20 Now then we are ambassadors for Christ, as though God did beseech you by us: we pray you in Christ's stead, be ye reconciled to God.
21 For he hath made him to be sin for us, who knew no sin; that we might be made the righteousness of God in him.

Our sins were judged, buried with Christ's blood, and forgotten when Christ gave His life.
Romans 5:8-11

But God commendeth his love toward us, in that, while we were yet sinners, Christ died for us.
9 Much more then, being now justified by his blood, we shall be saved from wrath through him.
10 For if, when we were enemies, we were reconciled to God by the death of his Son, much more, being reconciled, we shall be saved by his life.
11 And not only so, but we also joy in God through our Lord Jesus Christ, by whom we have now received the atonement.

It is by having this faith in Christ that all who will believe are saved from God's coming wrath and judgement.
1 Corinthians 15:1-4

Moreover, brethren, I declare unto you the gospel which I preached unto you, which also ye have received, and wherein ye stand;
2 By which also ye are saved, if ye keep in memory what I preached unto you, unless ye have believed in vain.
3 For I delivered unto you first of all that which I also received, how that Christ died for our sins according to the scriptures;
4 And that he was buried, and that he rose again the third day according to the scriptures:


Please refrain from answering off topic questions.
